# Anyone ever get a an OMF from Premier successfully into Pro Tools?

Tags: omf, post-production, workflow, pro-tools

I've had nothing but trouble for the past few weeks trying to get this figured out. Its a feature film that got trimmed down to 64 minutes and I haven't been able to get it into a decent Pro Tools session. I've done multiple OMF's in order to not go over the 2GB limit. We've done a track at a time, turned it into OMF and either way we go, we can't get the tracks in properly. The audio files end up getting jumbled up and sync just ends up getting mucked up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are both you and the editor running the same OS? I've had issues relinking .wav OMFs created on a PC into a Mac PT rig. Converting them to .aif in the OMF export process solved the relinking problem.

Also, I've had unsolvable issues for exports over 20 minutes- any way to break the OMFs into reels?

Are the regions showing up where they should or is everything all scattered? Has the editor tried re-importing the OMFs into Premiere (or Audition) to make sure they aren't getting messed up on that end?

Comment: @Jessie.R- We broke down the single OMF into 3 separate OMF's since the film is long and gave Tracks 1 and 2 their own OMF's, due to most of the dialog being on those two and Tracks 3 through 7 in another OMF. When I try to open them up, Pro Tools can't automatically find the files and I have to link them manually. Once  I select the folder to relink them, they get jumbled up and a majority of the audio files are all scattered. Last night, he opened everything in Audition and everything linked up just fine.  

Comment: @Jessie.R- It worked after exporting a new OMF out of Audition. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah- I've heard of people using Audition as a sort of "translator", but it seems weird to me in this case because you'd think that Premiere and Audition would be using the same export engine. Weird!

Answer (score 0):

I've received working omf's from Premier in the past. The only issues I've run into are is when there are mixed audio formats in the Premier timeline (but don't know how this may or may not be affected in Pro Tools 10). MP3s in particular caused a fair number of problems.

Comment: Everything that I gave the editor were BWF files and I believe he converted those into AIFF files.

Comment: @Ruben - yeah, that problem omf was purely the editor's work...no audio that i provided in any way. sorry i can't be of more assistance.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Premiere? As I recall everything below CS3 was pretty buggy about OMF's. I believe there was a CS2 update that fixed that version, but I think I only got one OMF from that (as I recall it worked). The CS3 stuff all seemed to be fine - we did about 25 shorts for Parks Canada out of it.

Comment: @ Sonsey- He's running Premiere version 5.5 I believe or whatever the latest version of Premiere that came with CS5. 

Answer (score 0):

What you could try is importing the OMF in another DAW that allows OMF export and make a new OMF for PT. This has saved me a lot of headaches sometimes. I used Cubase back then, if i remember correctly.
Anyway OMF's can be a real headache, so hope this helps!

Arnoud

Answer (score 0):

First off, thanks for all your help for everyone that tried to answer my question. Earlier today I imported a new OMF that the editor got from Audition. He exported another OMF that he handed off to me yesterday, with a whole new set of audio files. Lo and behold, once I imported this OMF, it finally worked! I'm assuming that the reason why PT wasn't responding to all of the other OMF's was because it wasn't recognizing particular metadata or was just incomparable because they're built differently. Now that I know this, I will definitely pass on this info and make sure that no one else has this problem ever come up again.